# How to call functions set as properties of child functional components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app with multiple filters that share the same logic but with different inputs. Every filter has a different combination of inputs and some of those inputs are reused in different places, so I created some reusable components to be used like this:

```js
<Filter>
  <Filter.Input1 />
  <Filter.Input2 />
</Filter>
```

Filter component manipulates the query string and every Input component uses different letters and logic to set it. For now, the logic related to query string is inside Filter:

```js
const Filter = ({children}) => {
  const searchParams = getParams(); // returns an object with the query string params

  // Simplified version of current code to populate defaultValues
  const defaultValues = {
    a: searchParams?.a, // query string param for Input1
    b: searchParams?.b, // query string param for Input2
  }

  // Here is a hook that receives the defaultValues
  // On a second render this hook will ignore any new defaultValues

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    // More logic related to query string params
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {React.children.map(...) // Set some props on Input elements
    </form>
  )
}
```

The problem here is that I have to include the logic to populate the `defaultValues` for every possible Input component, no matter if it's being used and now it's growing in complexity. I want to split that logic into the child components and loop through them to invoke functions with that logic, so now I'm trying to do something like this:

```js
const Input1 = () => {...}
Input1.parseParams = (stringParams) => ({ a: stringParams.?a }) // Some components have a more complex logic

const Input2 = () => {...}
Input2.parseParams = (stringParams) => ({ b: stringParams.?b })

const Filter = ({children}) => {
  const searchParams = getParams();

  const defaultValues = React.children.map(children, child => {
    if (child?.type && child?.type?.parseParams) {
      return child.type.parseParams(searchParams);
    }
  })
}
```

It works, but I didn't see anything on the docs or somewhere else about the property `type` inside `child`. Also, I was aware of it containing the `parseParams` function after doing a `console.log`. I have never seen an approach like this, so my questions are:

1. Where can I find documentation about `type`?
2. Is this a valid approach or there is a better way to do it? I'm afraid that `type` could be an internal property that is not intended to be used like this.

PD: I think using refs will not work here because I need to do the form initialization on the first render and refs are assigned to the children on the return.

Comment: You might want to check that `type` is still present in the production build. Would be better to add a custom property on the function component to lookup the type.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen earlier such approach or use of type, but I have a suggestion,
Since you wrote some specific logic for each component (Input1, Input2), why don't you just pass searchParams to them and let them decide what to do with it?

You can make something like this:

```
React.children.map(children, child => {
    if (child?.type && child?.type?.parseParams) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { searchParams });
    }
  })
```

UPD: I noticed that you might want just to get some defaultValues in your parent filter component, I think you can provide your child components a method like "setDefaultValue" and pass searchParams to it. After your child component render, it will make all necessary logic and call setDefaultValue which will set state in your parent component. It should work

Comment: The problem is that I have a hook that is initialized with `defaultValues`. In the first render it will receive an empty object and on subsequent renders it will ignore the new default values. And because it's a hook, I can't call it conditionally to avoid calling it in the first render. I updated the code in my question to reflect that.